# php sql interchange two primary value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

```
$or1='607990';
$or2='607992';

UPDATE tbl_collection
SET or_number=
    CASE
        WHEN or_number='$or1'
        THEN $or2
        WHEN or_number='$or2'
        THEN $or1 
    END
    WHERE or_number IN($or2,$or1)

//Duplicate entry '607992' for key 'PRIMARY''
```

Comment: $or1='607990'; 
$or2='607992';

tbl_collection
or_number       or_datetime
607990             2016-08-12 11:41:47
607992             2016-08-10 10:41:00

expected output:
607990             2016-08-12 11:41:47
607992             2016-08-10 10:41:00

need help!thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
Execute the Two Queries
$or1= '607990';
$or2='607992';
$or3='607992'.'_';
 1. update `tbl_collection` collection
    set collection.id = (CASE WHEN collection.id='$or1' THEN '$or3' ELSE '$or1' END) where collection.id in ($or1,$or2)
 2. update `tbl_collection` collection
   set collection.id = (CASE WHEN collection.id='$or3' THEN '$or1' ELSE '$or2' END) where collection.id in ('or1','or3')
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the Primary key for or_number column...
There was no possible to interchange the values of column which have primary key

Comment: ok2. i think there is a possibility swapping values in primary key.

Comment: have you get the output with primary key